# SyntaxError: The requested module 'rxjs/ajax' does not provide an export named 'ajax'

Tags: ajax, rxjs

When I run `import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';` I get the following error,

```
(node:8582) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///home/..../foo.mjs:1
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'rxjs/ajax' does not provide an export named 'ajax'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:79:21)
```

Comment: What RxJS version you have?

Comment: @martin rxjs@6.3.3

Answer (score 2):

This is because Rx.js does not yet support real ES module syntax.

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4416